# Sierra Leone Ethnic Groups - Shapefile

Tags: uses-of-open-data, programming

I am looking for open data on the Sierra Leone Ethnic groups.
Preferably in Shapefile format or any other format that can be used on a map.

So far I created a map with the districts and their population (population was just for testing purposes) in R. Now I want to overlay these districts with the Ethnic groups located in Sierra Leone.
[Such as show in this image.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnic_groups_in_Sierra_Leone#/media/File:Sierra_leone_ethnic_1969.jpg)

My search on the internet didn't come up with any Shapefiles regarding Ethnic Groups in Sierra Leone. Maybe someone knows where I can find these?

Also if it's not to difficult and time consuming I can try to create one myself... Although some advice on this will be very helpful!

[image: Plot]

Comment: If R has image processing packages you could use them to discretise the ethnicity image to get shapes of the regions. Then rescale them to the long/lat  coordinates using the most southern, northern, eastern, and western points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google search:`african ethnic groups GIS`

First item: [ArcGIS.com | Feature Service - Ethnic Groups in Africa](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=cc2324e45ace44d09c333b4b4a1c14a3)

Answer (score 1):

There are several sources for this data, none of them are perfect:

- [Open Data portal](http://opendata.gov.sl/) for government of Sierra Leone
- Official source of demographic and ethic group data in Sierra Leone is Statistics Sierra Leone, which last conducted [a census in 2004](http://opendata.gov.sl/dataset/sierra-leone-population-and-housing-census).  They launch new census in December 2015, but it may be a while before results are complete.
- [Shapefiles from International Conflict Research](http://www.icr.ethz.ch/data/other/greg) (the excellent example from @Edmund)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, already came across some of these sites but couldn't find enough detailed information for my needs. However, shapefiles from International Conflict Research (@Emund) fulfills my needs!